# multiselect dropdown for angular 1.4.x version

Tags: angularjs

My angular version is 1.4.7 and I wanted to use the angular-multiselect-dropdown plugin for selecting multiple values from dropdown. Most of the plugins support  version >=1.5.x . If you could see [cdnpkg](https://www.cdnpkg.com/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect) and [github](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect)

Are there any plugin that supports 1.4.x version for multiselect dropdown?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey Chris you can use bootstrap or normal HTML multi-select checkbox and populate them with ng-repeat setting their id and values dynamic
like 
<div>
                    <input  dir-click-anywhere="this[$index] = true" type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled{{dropdown.id + dropdown.display}}" ng-model="dropdown.checked">
                    <label for="filled{{dropdown.id + dropdown.display}}"></label>
                   </div>
where dropdown.id and dropdown.display are dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Angular ui-select](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/), it supports from 1.2.x.

```
[Preview][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

GO through this http://embed.plnkr.co/xWvfWYjaW7TThKZONkv5/ this is exactly what you want.
You can try like this,it works :

```js
var app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('selectIssue',function($scope){
  $scope.names = [{
    name:"Rohit"
  },
  {
    name:"Virat"
  },
  {
    name:"Ritesh"
  }];
  $scope.selectedName = [];
})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="selectIssue">
  <div>
   <select multiple ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="name.name for name in names track by name.name"></select>
  </div>
    Selected value table :
    <div>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="n in selectedName">
          <td>{{n.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried this code, but when I'm adding  the keyword 'multiple' in the <select> tag, then the dropdown would not be shown. Instead the complete list gets displayed as in a div.

Comment: @Chris go through the link at the top of my answer, you will like it.